# Split Button and Menu to Button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qmenu

I want to get dropdown when I click on button and pick up a some action. 
How could these behaviour shown on images below achieve with `QPushbutton` and `PyQt5`:

**There are 2 ways to do it as below:**

> 1- Split Button

[image]

> 2 - Menu and subnemu to button.

[image]

```
class Button(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(500,500,200,100)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button with menu")
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Button()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How could I achieve those behaviour? Thanks for any support.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a popup menu to a `QPushbutton`. The button will become a menu button:

```
    w = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(w)

    button = QPushButton("Click me")
    layout.addWidget(button)
    w.show()

    menu = QMenu()
    menu.addAction("Action 1")
    menu.addAction("Action 2")
    menu.addAction("Action 3")

    button.setMenu(menu)
```

Comment: I can not use your solution since you do not adopt it to my provided code!

Comment: I added a menu to a button as you asked. What is bothering you?